# Is there easy way to find "distance from the curve" function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there easy way to find function $D:\Re^2 \to \Re$ that for a curve given by plot of some function $y=f(x)$ and point $(x,y)$ splits out distance of this point from the curve? I assume that the distance of a point $p$ from the curve is given by maximum radius of a circle centered at a point $p$ that don't intersect the curve, or is tangent to the curve. For example when the curve is given by $y=x^2$ then $D(0,1)={\frac{\sqrt3}2}$
[image]

I've found that $$D(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-q(x,y))^2+(y+f(q(x,y)))^2}$$ where $$q(x,y)= \delta_p(f(p)^2+p^2-2yf(p)-2xp)$$ $\delta_p(g(p))$ is argument for which function g has global minimum, if function g depends on more then one variable then $\delta_p(g(p))$ gives global minimum of $g$ "treating" variables other then $p$ as parameters. If function has more than one global minimum then it doesn't matter which one will you chose to use in the formula for q(x,y).

 Unfortunately formula shown above don't allow to easily determinate what D(x,y) is for most of the curves.

Thanks for all the help in solving this problem.

Comment: Method of [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) can be used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I've tried to apply Lagrange multiplier to this problem, but I didn't come up to anything nice.

Comment: The short answer is going to be “no.” In general, there isn’t a “nice” closed-form formula. You have to solve the Lagrange multiplier equations on a case-by-case basis. Equivalently, you must find points on the curve for which the normal line passes through the given fixed point. That also doesn’t have a “neat” closed-form formula in general.